# Google Freebase API to fetch Name, Image and Text at once

Tags: php, api, freebase

Presently what I do is call the following APIs

```
$url    = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query='. $query; // to fetch name and id
```

and using the id from the result of above API, I execute two more APIs to get the text and image

```
$url = 'https://usercontent.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/image' . $entity_id; // to fecth image

$url    = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/' . $entity_id; // to fetch description
```

is there any API/URL for freebase, such that, I get all these three at once ?????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're never going to get different media types (e.g. JPEG & JSON) in the same call, but you can use the Search API [output parameters](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-output#advanced-output) to get the name, text blurb, and image URLs.  The images will still need to be fetched separately.

For example, if you wanted the names and descriptions in Japanese & English as well as the images for topics which match the search term "Barack Obama" you could use a query like:

[https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=%22Barack%20Obama%22&indent=true&output=%28%20name%20description%3Awikipedia%20/common/topic/image%29&lang=en%2Cja](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=%22Barack%20Obama%22&indent=true&output=%28%20name%20description%3awikipedia%20/common/topic/image%29&lang=en,ja)

This also returns topics like his inauguration, so you could filter by type if you knew it ahead of time or do the query using the topic ID or MID if you knew them.

Comment: Thanks , this helped a lot, now the results coming faster, else I had to call the api for description separately. Can I save the image I fetch with .jpg extension

Comment: @TomMorris, would you mind providing an example of this in your answer? I'm rather confused about what the query would like after adding a search term like "Barack Obama".

Comment: I've added URL which is a slight tweak of one copied from the documentation page that I pointed to before.  It's pretty straightforward, but for a 50 point bounty, I'm happy to help. :-)

Comment: @Xeoncross check out the edit in my ques to see how I have implemented it. Tom Morris rocks.....

Comment: @TomMorris not sure, but cant give another answer to the same ques ?

Comment: @Deepanshu, thank you also for updating your question.

Comment: Thanks @Xeoncross! It looks like I got award the bounty after all, even though the documentation explicitly says that only answers posted after the bounty was available qualify.  Perhaps editing the answer counted to reset clock.  In any case, I'm happy the answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as far as I know.